# DataTables Error when using AjaxSource

Tags: datatables

I am getting this error when I try to connect a DataTable to an WebApi controller:

```
"DataTables warning:  table id=mytable - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0."
```

When I view the response from a WebApi controller in get this:

```
{"sEcho":"1","iTotalRecords":2,"iTotalDisplayRecords":2,"aaData":[{"id":2,"name":"Name2","description":"Description2"},{"id":4,"name":"Name2","description":"Description2"}]}
```

My DataTable code looks like this:

```
$(function () {

    $('#mytable').dataTable({
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "api/getmystuff",
        "sAjaxDataProp": "aaData",
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "Columns": [
                           { "mData": "Id" },
                           { "mData": "Name" },
                           { "mData": "Description" }
        ]

    });
});
```

Here is my table markup:

```
 <table id="materials" class="grid">
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
 <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Is there something wrong with my json response?  Or with how I am implementing dataTable?   I have check through several examples and I don't see anything obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was with how I defined the columns in the dataTable javascript.   Rather than using:

```
"Columns": [
                       { "mData": "Id" },
                       { "mData": "Name" },
                       { "mData": "Description" }
    ]
```

I should have used:

```
"aoColumns": [
                       { mData: "Id" },
                       { mData: "Name" },
                       { mData: "Description" }
    ]
```

Notice the missing quotes around mData and Columns changed to aoColumns